# No puedo agregar datos a mi transmisión con stream.sink.add dentro de una solicitud de búsqueda

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy haciendo un formulario para hacer una búsqueda, en el cual tengo un botón que hace la solicitud de publicación http dentro de mi función getsearchguia, procedo a enviar la respuesta a mi flujo y luego lo llamo en otra vista y obtengo los datos pero cuando hago un escuchador de mi flujo imprimo = falso que los datos no fueron agregados

1. btn:

```
     Widget btnBuscarEnvio() {
   
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        setState(() {
        botonAnimated = false;
        });
        print(botonAnimated);
        var resp =  await searchguia.searchguia( guia:myGuia.text, code:myCodigo.text); ////peticon de datos de envio
        if(resp['valor']==1){
          setState(() {
            botonAnimated = true;
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, DetailsEnv.name);
          });
        }
        if(resp['valor'] == 0){
          setState(() {
            botonAnimated = true;
          });
          }
        print(botonAnimated);
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
        child: BotonSearchBtn(estado: botonAnimated, title: "Buscar"),
      ),
    );
  }
```

2. Method SearchGuia

```
  Future searchguia(
      {required String guia, int seconds = 0, required String code}) async {
    String url = Overskull.urlBuscar2;
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      "serie": '',
      "numguia": guia,
      "aleatorio": code,
      "tipo": '2'
    };
    final resp =
        await Internet.httpPost(url: url, body: body, seconds: seconds);
    if (resp["valor"] != 0) {
     // DatosEnvio datosEnvio = DatosEnvio.fromJson(resp['data'][0]);
      //List<Datum> datos =  datosEnvio.data;
       _searchEnvio.sink.add(resp['data'][0]);
       print("valor-->1 add al stream ");
     
     
    }
     print(resp);
     print(_searchEnvio.hasListener);
     return resp;
  }
```

Cuando se inicia el botón, no agrega los datos a la secuencia y ya no puedo usar los datos en la otra vista, me da nulo y no puedo usar mi streambuilder, pero cuando comienzo mi guía de búsqueda dentro del estado de inicio
desde la otra vista allí, si se agregan los datos, hashlistener es verdadero, no entiendo por qué al presionar mi botón no agrega los datos y en el estado de inicio de la otra vista si lo agrega, lo siento, pero estoy nuevo
Y no entiendo por qué sucede esto, sería de mucha ayuda si hubiera una solución.

```
  SearchGUiaBloc search = SearchGUiaBloc();
  @override
  void initState() {
    search.searchguia(guia: '2972857', code: 'CDCP');
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes! Como es el sitio en español, debo pedirte que por favor [edites (el enlace estará siempre bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/467132/edit) y traduzcas tu pregunta a español, incluyendo el título.